# Determine if ONLY ONE option is selected in multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With the following code, I am using a multi select box to enable the user to select multiple options. I am displaying a preview image of the selected option in another div when the user selects one of the options.

This all works, however I would like to be able to update the div with the image preview to show a placeholder image when more than one item is selected.

Ideas?

```
<select multiple id="opt1-opts">
      <option value="diesel_nova_rts_06_1996">Nova RTS-06 - 1996</option>
      <option value="diesel_nova_rts_06_1998">Nova RTS-06 - 1998</option>
      <option value="diesel_nova_rts_06_1999">Nova RTS-06 - 1999</option>
      <option>Nova 40LF - 2011</option>
      <option value="new_flyer_40lf_2011">New Flyer 40LF - 2011</option>
      <option value="orion_v_1995">Orion V WC - 1995</option>
      <option value="orion_v_1996">Orion V WC - 1996</option>
      <option value="orion_v_1999">Orion V WC - 1999</option>
      <option>Orion 40LF - 2011</option>
</select>
<div id="dialog-bus-type-image-info-area">
      <img src="imgs/LFS60102.JPG" border=0>
</div>

//bus type dialog scripts
$("#opt1-opts").change(function(){
    $("#dialog-bus-type-image-info-area").empty().append("<img src='imgs/busTypes/" + $("#opt1-opts option:selected").val() +".jpg' border='0'/>");
});
```

Comment: how does this fail? An error description would definitely aid clarity

Comment: I'd like to determine if multiple items are selected.
> If so, show placeholder image
> Else, show the image of the one item selected.

Comment: Inside onchange handler, `$(this).val().length` will return number of options selected  http://jsfiddle.net/Wbg2K/

Comment: The final code that works is: 

//bus type dialog scripts
 $("#opt1-opts").change(function(e){
  if ($(this).val().length == 1)
   $("#dialog-bus-type-image-info-area").empty().append("<img src='imgs/busTypes/" + $("#opt1-opts option:selected").val() +".jpg' border='0'/>");
  else 
   $("#dialog-bus-type-image-info-area").empty();
 });

Answer (score 2):

`$("#opt1-opts option:selected").length` will give you how many children options are selected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/zQQbL/

HTML:

```
<select multiple id="opt1-opts">
      <option value="diesel_nova_rts_06_1996">Nova RTS-06 - 1996</option>
      <option value="diesel_nova_rts_06_1998">Nova RTS-06 - 1998</option>
      <option value="diesel_nova_rts_06_1999">Nova RTS-06 - 1999</option>
      <option>Nova 40LF - 2011</option>
      <option value="new_flyer_40lf_2011">New Flyer 40LF - 2011</option>
      <option value="orion_v_1995">Orion V WC - 1995</option>
      <option value="orion_v_1996">Orion V WC - 1996</option>
      <option value="orion_v_1999">Orion V WC - 1999</option>
      <option>Orion 40LF - 2011</option>
</select>
<div id="outputs"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#opt1-opts").change(function(){
    var selectCount = $("#opt1-opts :selected").length;
    if (selectCount == 1){
        $('#outputs').html("ONLY one selected");
    }else{
        $('#outputs').html("");
    };
});
```

That should do it . . .